# Extensions without a UI

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm just learning about creating extensions, and for those that don't have a UI is the chrome.manifest necessary?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `chrome.manifest` in your extension then Firefox will automatically create an empty one. So strictly speaking it isn't necessary. However, there isn't much that you could do without any entries to `chrome.manifest`:

- If you want to run code in each browser window you will need to apply a XUL overlay to the window that will load the script. This means that you will need a `chrome://` namespace and an overlay definition in the `chrome.manifest`.
- If you simply want to create an XPCOM component that will wait for some event to happen (e.g. browser startup, HTTP request made etc.), you will need to [register this component in chrome.manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0#Component_manifests) or it will be ignored.

The only things that would work without a `chrome.manifest` are NPAPI plugins or search engines but that's probably not what you are interested in.

Anyway, if you are a newbie and your add-on isn't supposed to have a user interface, maybe you should look at the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) instead. The Add-on Builder lets you create an add-on with a few lines of code, without worrying about directory structures, namespaces and such.